# RethinkDB- unable to migrate in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, rethinkdb, laravel-5.5, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to create a demo of RethinkDB + Laravel following this [git repo](https://github.com/duxet/laravel-rethinkdb) and there I got stuck will migrating my migrations. When I try to migrate using `php artisan migrate` I got this error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                                                                      
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Users::{closure}() must be an instance of duxet\Rethinkdb\Schema\Blueprint, instance of Illuminate\Database\Sc  
  hema\Blueprint given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xyzz-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php on line 164
```

I looked into this issue in repo but there it is listed in bug and was not properly addressed. Is there anyone who have encountered this and has the idea about how to fix this bug?

here is my migration that I have made.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use duxet\Rethinkdb\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Users extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users',function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix this issue by this command

```
php artisan migrate --database=rethinkdb
```

as I have `DB_CONNECTION='rethinkdb` in my `database.php` file also you will find other issues too when you get pass this error and for that I have forked [this repo](https://github.com/duxet/laravel-rethinkdb) and requested a pull request. Till then you can fix it by yourself.

**Issue #1** and [Issue#39](https://github.com/duxet/laravel-rethinkdb/issues/39) of repo

For this you need to specify database name while migrating , if you have multiple dbs as by default it will go for `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` like this

```
php artisan migrate --database=rethinkdb
```

and then you will get another error in `Blueprint.php` stated here

> [ErrorException]
>   Declaration of duxet\RethinkDB\Schema\Blueprint::index($column,
>   $options = NULL) should be compatible with
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::index($columns, $name =
>   NULL, $algorithm = NULL)

You can fix this by making an edit in `Blueprint.php` by replacing

```
public function index($column, $options = null)
```

by

```
public function index($columns, $name = NULL, $algorithm = NULL)
```

**Issue #2** and [Issue#41](https://github.com/duxet/laravel-rethinkdb/issues/41) which states as

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Access level to duxet\Rethinkdb\Query\Builder::$operators must be
>   public (as in class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)

For fixing this issue you have to make an edit in `Builder.php`

change the `$operator` access type to `public` from `protected`

```
public $operators = [
        '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=',
        'like', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike',
        '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
        'rlike', 'regexp', 'not regexp',
        '~', '~*', '!~', '!~*',
        'contains', 'exists', 'type', 'mod', 'size',
    ];
```

**Issue #3**

After that you will find another issue which is also there is repo as [Issue#42](https://github.com/duxet/laravel-rethinkdb/issues/42)

For this you have to edit `Builder.php` where you need to replace

```
 public function groupBy()
```

by

```
 public function groupBy(...$groups)
```

**Issue #4**

Now after fixing all this issue you will encounter another issue which I discovered myself today while fixing all these issues.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>   Call to a member function supportsSchemaTransactions() on null

To fix this issue you need to follow the following steps.
1. create a file `Grammar.php` in `src/Schema` namespace and paste this code.

```
<?php

namespace duxet\RethinkDB\Schema;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar as BaseGrammar;

/**
 * Class Grammar
 *
 * @package Moloquent\Schema
 */
class Grammar extends BaseGrammar {
}
```

2. Now you need to modify `Connection.php`

firstly, add this

```
use duxet\Rethinkdb\Schema\Grammar;
```

and then inside `public function __construct(array $config)` add this

```
$this->schemaGrammar = new Grammar();
```

All the above things I have fixed in [forked version](https://github.com/wmtoscar/laravel-rethinkdb) and made a pull request. Hope this will help you and you won't need to scratching your head like I did :)

**UPDATE**

On 13th Novemeber, pull request is accepted and now you won't need to do the following steps if you found any trouble you can still give a try.